# Syntax error when trying to create new empty list in Python

Tags: syntax

I'm embarking on my Project Euler adventure and the first line of my Python code is tripping me up.  The error I get for the code below is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 3
    3multlist = []
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Which makes NO sense because I've verified up and down that the line in question does have proper syntax!

Code below:

```
3multlist = []
5multlist = []

3starter = 0
5starter = 0

While (3starter < 1000):

    3starter = 3starter + 3
    3multlist.append(3starter)

While (5starter < 1000):
    5starter = 5starter + 3
    5multlist.append(5starter)

b = sum(3multlist)
c = sum(5multlist)
d = b + c

print d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because variable name can not start with a numeral.Below are the variable naming convention rules
Variables names must start with a letter or an underscore, such as:
_

- underscore
- underscore_

The remainder of your variable name may consist of letters, numbers and underscores.

- password1
- n00b
- un_der_scores

Names are case sensitive.
case_sensitive, CASE_SENSITIVE, and Case_Sensitive are each a different variable

Correct version of your program would be

```
multlist = []
multlist = []
starter = 0
starter = 0

while (starter < 1000):

    starter = starter + 3
    multlist.append(starter)

while (starter < 1000):
    starter = starter + 3
    multlist.append(starter)
b = sum(multlist)
c = sum(multlist)
d = b + c

print(d)
```

If you are using python 3 you need to use brackets with print statement else you can drop them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like python does not like the number in front of the list declaration

try multlist3 rather than 3multlist

Comment: yes, I can't remember any programming language which supports variable name starting with a numbers !